# MongoDB : CursorNotFound in the middle of a query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using `MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7` and in the middle of a long query (Double forEach ~30k*230k entries) the query stop and I got `CursorNotFound`

Here is the query.

```
db.EUCtrCopy.find().forEach(function (data){
    db.USFull.find({$or:[{"clinical_study.brief_title" : data.ASection.FullTitle },{"clinical_study.official_title" : data.ASection.FullTitle },{"clinical_study.id_info.org_study_id" : data.ASection.SponsorProtocolNumber}]}).forEach(function (val) {
        db.USEUOverlap.insert({"USId": val._id, "EUId" : data._id})
        print("It's a match ! ("+data._id+")");
    });
});
```

I read that when you are idling in the MongoDB Shell you can have the `CursorNotFound` problem. But it happens right in the middle of the query.
How can I get read of this error ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not the sort of thing you should be running in the shell. Unless there is some specific reason you cannot do this then you should in fact upgrade to MongoDB 3.2 at least and use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) and let all of this happen on the server itself.

Comment: If you cannot upgrade then use [`.addOption()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.addOption/#cursor.addOption) with [`DBQuery.option.noTimeout`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.addOption/#DBQuery.Option.noTimeout). But the former suggestion is the far more sane approach.

Comment: Thank you @neil-lunn, what do you mean by not running in the shell. How can I ? "mongo Database --eval script.js"
Updated to 3.4 CE.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry I am no expert like you. Already updated. Could you be more specific ? Especially about alternatives...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation for **EUCtrCopy** collection Use `$lookup` **USFull** with one field by giving local field and foreign field then add `$filter` for doing the rest condition in this pipeline finally use `$out` pipeline with **USEUOverlap** to get the result as a collection


For reference [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)
[$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: Thanks you very much. Will try that